# How to build API that will return HTML for the site and JSON for other clients

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have started learning DRF just a while ago and had a little question -
how can I code one API that will return HTML for the site that I am currently working on and return JSON format for other "clients"(e.g. mobile apps, desktop, etc)?

I have tried to search for this information, but didn't found any answering content.

The only way I see is to create default Django views for the site and create separated API's for other requests. Can anybody tell me if I am right and need to do so, or there is some code that is solving my problem?

Comment: please describe what you understand as "the site" and "other clients". What exactly is the difference you want to identify to switch between json and html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, you can think of it as a whole separate set of views, urls and instead of models you have a serializer.  Within you're app you can create an API folder.  Within that directory you will need to have an '_ _ init _ _.py', 'urls.py', 'views.py' and a 'serializers.py'. Its analogous to creating a standard url, view, model structure to display an HTML page, but without the HTML template.  Make distinct urls for the serializers too. For example for login do something like this:

```
path('my_app_api/login', serializer_view)
```

Youtube has tons of videos if you search django rest framework

Comment: Thank you! I really needed that answer afap!